# Finding the column total in an array

Tags: c#, java, c++, arrays, grid

I have an 1-dimensional array with random elements, got through a m*n grid. I want to find out the row total and column total, present in it.

Here is how the 1 dimensional array is:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

I want to treat it like :

`01`  `02`   `03`  `04`   `05`

`06`   `07`   `08`  `09`   `10`

`11`  `12`  `13`  `14`  `15`

`16` `17` `18` `19` `20`

Now i want to find the reo total and column total.
Row total is done as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
            {
                rowTotal[i] += numbers[temp + j];
            }               
            temp += totalColumns;
        }
```

I am trying to do the same with Column.
Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalColumns; i++)
        {
            tempk = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < totalRows; j++)
            {
                blockTotal[i] += numbers[i+j+tempk];
               tempk += totalColumns;

            }
        }
```

Am not able to get the column total, as intended. Please Help.

Comment: Why not use a multidimensional array instead?

Comment: you should be able to get your result by using the first loop, and replace `rowTotal[i] +=` by `columnTotal[j] +=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get both in the same loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
    {
        rowTotal[i] += numbers[i * totalColumns + j];
        blockTotal[j] += numbers[i * totalColumns + j];
    }            
}
```

Comment: This code is working only for M*M matrix. Not for M*N. How can i modify this code, so as to make it work for M*N?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to write a little method that translates a "logical" (row, col) address to an index:

```
int numberAt(int row, int col)
{
    return numbers[row * totalColumns + col];
}

int[] colTotals = new int[totalColumns];
int[] rowTotals = new int[totalRows];

for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < totalColumns; ++col)
    {
        int number = numberAt(row, col);
        rowTotals[row] += number; 
        colTotals[col] += number;
    }
}
```

---

Edit in response to question in comments below:

Here's a complete compilable example that demonstrates it working on a non-square array:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        // Array will 4x3 (rows x cols):
        //
        //  1  2  3 |  6
        //  4  5  6 | 15
        //  7  8  9 | 24
        // 10 11 12 | 33
        // ---------
        // 22 26 30

        int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToArray();
        int totalColumns = 3;
        int totalRows    = 4;

        int numberAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return numbers[row * totalColumns + col];
        }

        void test()
        {
            int[] colTotals = new int[totalColumns];
            int[] rowTotals = new int[totalRows];

            for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; ++row)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < totalColumns; ++col)
                {
                    int number = numberAt(row, col);
                    rowTotals[row] += number;
                    colTotals[col] += number;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Row totals");

            foreach (int rowTotal in rowTotals)
                Console.Write(rowTotal + " ");

            Console.WriteLine("\nCol totals");

            foreach (int colTotal in colTotals)
                Console.Write(colTotal + " ");

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working only for M*M matrix. Not for M*N. How can i modify this code, so as to make it work for M*N?

Comment: @Vivek It *does* work for M*N - I've added sample code to my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Total by rows

```
for(int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < totalColumns; c++)
  {
    rowTotal[r] += numbers[r * totalColumns + c];
  }
}
```

Total by columns

```
for(int c = 0; c < totalColumns; c++)
{
  for(int r = 0; r < totalRows; r++)
  {
    colTotal[c] += numbers[r * totalColumns + c];
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `r * totalColumns + c`, not `r * totalColumns + totalColumns`

Comment: This code is working only for M*M matrix. Not for M*N. How can i modify this code, so as to make it work for M*N?

Comment: M -> totalRows, N -> totalColumns